# app persistence using dreamweaver, js, jQuery, and phone gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, persistence, dreamweaver

I was wondering if it possible to have user entered data persist in an app built with dreamweaver, js, jquery mobile, and phone gap as the host.

For example, one of my pages has a date picker with text areas underneath to enter in specific information for that day.  I want the user to be able to choose a date and save the info for that day and be able to navigate back to the day with all of the information they entered.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements there are multiple possibilities to store data between pages, just a rough list:

1. URL-Parameters (only current browser session)
2. Cookies (browser session, or persistent)
3. Local-storage or session-storage in the browser (persistent or session)
4. If using a server, you could also store your data in the session on your server (usually session)
5. Store data in a database/cloud, ... (persistent)

"Session" means, that the data is lost, when the browser is closed. "Persistent" means, that your data will be held for a longer time, even after closing your browser (thus ending the session).

Hope that helps